# Measuring the speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light, measurements

We all know that the speed of light is $299792458~\textrm{m/s}$. Here we use meters as measuring sticks to measure the speed of light .

But how is a meter  defined? It is defined using the speed of light. Here there is a weird circular reasoning. How can this be avoided? Do we have to accept the speed of light as $299792458~\textrm{m/s}$ and not measure it at all?

Comment: "Do we have to accept the speed of light as $299792458$ $m$/$s$ and not measure it at all?" - yes, that's how the metre is defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the speed of light defined as 299792458 m/s?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9314/)