# Is it possible to distinguish the type of space according to the speed of light in vacuum?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, refraction, physical-constants

Why is the speed of light 300 000 km/s? The speed of light is slower in glass, water and diamond. Is the speed of light in water, glass and diamond also absolute? Can we calculate the material such as glass by calculating the speed of light in objects? From these questions, I finally want to answer this question, is it possible to distinguish the type of space according to the speed of light in vacuum?

Main question is **Why** is the speed of light 300 000 km/s?
is it possible to distinguish the type of space according to the speed of light in vacuum?

Comment: In a suitably chosen system of physical units the speed of light is 1. The numerical value in SI units is simply a consequence of the choice of units. Change from meter to furlongs and from seconds to fortnights and you get c=1.8026×10^12 furlongs/fortnights.

Comment: The speed of light in a medium of refractive index n is c/n. So, you can calculate its refractive index from the speed of light in a medium.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3644/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56973/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the speed of light $c$ have the value it does?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56973/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this answers your question, but $c\approx 300km/s$ because, when solving Maxwell equations in vaccum we get the equation of a wave (electromagnetic wave) with $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu _o\epsilon _o}}$, if we plug in the value of this constants, then we get $\approx 300km/s$.

And yeah, light travels at different speeds in different mediums because of the refractive index, n, which can vary in different madiums. This index, $n=\frac{c}{v}$ can be predicted through different theoretical models that study the interaction between light and atoms (for example Lorentz's model).

Comment: To add to this correct answer, the equation given uses $\mu_0\epsilon_0$, which are the correct numbers for the constants that matter: the permeability and permittivity of free space, which are measured constants describing a vacuum.  Each material has its own permeability, $\mu$ and its own permittivity, $\epsilon$ (we only use the 0 subscript for free-space).  With those numbers, you can calculate the speed of light in that material.  Understanding what causes a material to have a given $\mu$ or $\epsilon$ is a much more complicated question.

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding the speed of light is that it is an electromagnetic wave.  It is governed by [Maxwell's Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations), a set of four equations that have been found to correctly describe how electricity and magnetism works.  If you look at those equations, you find that they admit a wave equation, which permits a localized packet of electrical and magnetic energy to propagate forward.  You can calculate the velocity of that wave, which is $v=\frac 1{\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}}$, where $\mu$ is the permeability of that space, a purely magnetic constant, and $\epsilon$ is the permittivity of that space, a purely electrical constant.  If you can measure this magnetic constant and this electrical constant, you can predict the speed of light in that medium.

We typically see this equation written specifically for the vacuum of space, where $\mu=\mu_0$ and $\epsilon=\epsilon_0$.  This shows that there *is* a speed of light in the vacuum of space, defined by $c=\frac 1{\sqrt{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}}$.  These are measured constants of the vacuum that you can (in theory) measure on your own if you wish.

The absolute-ness of the speed of light is a much larger discussion.  The above parts don't require any discussion of relativity.  There's many good descriptions of this, but to give you a quick sample, consider a man throwing a baseball forward on a train.  The man can pitch at 40m/s, and the train is moving 50m/s.  Its easy to see that the man pitching will see the ball as moving forward at 40m/s, but someone on the ground would see it moving at 90m/s, because the effect of the trains motion and the ball's motion would add together.

Now what happens when you try to throw it faster and faster.  You start to run into speed limits, like the speed of sound.  Were you to have the train traveling much faster, you could eventually get to the point where throwing the ball would cause it to exceed the speed of sound, suffering massive drag.  But what speed do you use?  The 40m/s that the pitcher sees?  Or the much higher speed the outside observer sees?  The answer is intuitive.  The ball is traveling through a medium: air.  Its the ball speed with respect to the air that matters.  If the train is enclosed, the air around the ball is also moving at the speed of the train, and the ball will never see super-sonic effects from a human pitcher.  On the other hand, if the train is open-air, with the air whizzing past the pitcher and the ball, we might have to consider super-sonic effects.  We say the air's frame of reference is "privileged" in the sense that velocities measured in that frame correctly capture speed limited effects.

But what about a vacuum?  We see that there is indeed a speed of electromagnetic wave propagation in the vacuum.  We can calculate it, and we can demonstrate it.  But a vacuum isn't a medium, right?  There's no air molecules with which to develop a privileged frame?  At first we thought there might be.  We thought there might be a substance that was called the "luminiferous aether," and it would have some privileged frame.  So as good scientists, we went out to measure it.

... and we failed.  If we measured the speed of a train in the direction of its travel, it might travel at 50m/s.  If we measure it in the perpendicular direction, across the tracks, it would be traveling at 0m/s.  This is intuitive.  But for some reason, no matter what direction we looked, the speed of light was the same.  This is not intuitive.  It doesn't work like our normal intuition about human-sized physics works.  But it's what we've observed about the universe.

We say "the speed of light in a vacuum is absolute" for this reason.  It doesn't seem to matter whether we're on a train traveling 50m/s "north" or a train traveling 100m/s "east."  No matter what, when we measure the speed of light in a vacuum, it's the same, *even though we changed frames of reference*.  This is *weird*.  It'd be like if you and a friend were driving in cars next to each other, both at a speed of 60mph as seen by an outside observer and *somehow* your friend is passing you at 60mph.  Normal material physics would suggest your friend would just be keeping up with you, with a relative velocity of 0mph.  Light just doesn't follow those rules.

A lot of debate occurred on this, and finally Einstein put forth his theory of relativity, suggesting time and space are relative to the observer.  This is totally uninutitive for those of us used to human-scale speeds, but it has proven to be extremely accurate in predicting many effects that turned out to be true.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your original question is Yes, you can distinguish the type of space by the speed of light, because the speed of light is a measurement of the speed of time.   But keep in mind that you can only do this if you are not in the same region of space as the light you are measuring.

I'm sure you are aware of gravitational time dilation.  So imagine that we dig a tunnel right through Venus. Then shine a laser from Mercury towards Earth. It will take a certain amount of time for that laser to reach Earth.  But if Venus passes in between Mercury and Earth and the laser goes through the tunnel, then it will take longer for that laser to reach Earth because of the gravitational time dilation surrounding Venus.

Now if you were on Venus you would not see this effect, because your own clock would match with the local gravitational time dilation. That confirms that the local speed of light is always 300,000 km/s. It can only be seen by a distant observer, such as a person on Earth who is working with a clock running at a different rate of time.

The universe is full of different regions of spacetime, based on the nearby planets and galaxies causing warping of the local spacetime.   So yes you can distinguish them by the speed of light passing through each region which merely reflects the speed of time in each region.