# Experimental determination of speed of light

Tags: visible-light, experimental-physics, speed-of-light, metrology

How is the speed of light measured by the most current method i.e. using lasers and atomic clocks? Alternatively, is there a better method?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1383/2451

Answer (score 1):

The speed of light can't be measured anymore (in SI units) because it has had a defined value since 1983. See [Why do universal constants have the values they do?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144262/why-do-universal-constants-have-the-values-they-do)

Before 1983, the meter was defined in terms of the wavelength of a certain emission line of krypton 86. The second is also defined in terms of an atomic standard (the frequency of a transition in cesium 133). Therefore before 1983 it was possible to measure the speed of light, and such a measurement would have consisted of comparing these two atomic standards.

Comment: We still can measure the time it takes for a light pulse to travel a certain distance. It doesn't matter if we use the result to determine c or the length of our meter or the accuracy of our clock. If I read the question correctly it asks for current experimental methods employed.

Comment: @guntbert: To do what you propose, you would have to have length and distance standards. The length and distance standards are such that c has a defined value.

Comment: Maybe it is a language problem on my side (determining vs measuring?): I thought I proposed to describe an experiment to *confirm* that my "meter" is really "the length of the path travelled by light in vacuum during a time interval of 1/299 792 458 of a second".

Comment: @guntbert: What you propose sounds like a method of checking a secondary standard for length against the primary standard for length. That's fine, but it's not a determination of $c$.